# Checkpoints, unknown files, intermediate processing - missing wildcards problem

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to use checkpoints for the first time to split a file into multiple fixed-sized chunks, do something to each chunk, and then merge those processed chunked files.

Here is a trimmed-down implementation I have, that doesn't work.
First rule splits the requested fastq file into fixed size chunks, and it's a checkpoint:

```
checkpoint chunk_fastq:
    input:
        fastq=lambda wc: (
            f"LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wc.library][wc.run]["12".index(wc.side)]
        ),
    params:
        chunksize=lambda wc: config["map"]["chunksize"] * 4,
    threads: 4
    output:
        directory("outputs/fastq_chunks/{library}.{run}.{side,[12]}"),
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output};
        zcat {input.fastq} | split -l {params.chunksize} -d \
            --filter 'bgzip -c -@ {threads} > $FILE.fastq.gz' - \
            {output}/
        """
```

Then I have two intermediate rules connected by a pipe that should process each chunk generated in the checkpoint in the way I need:

```
rule map_chunks_bwa:
    input:
        reads=lambda wildcards: expand(
            "outputs/fastq_chunks/{library}.{run}.{side}/{chunk_id}.fastq.gz",
            library=wildcards.library,
            run=wildcards.run,
            side=[1, 2],
            chunk_id=wildcards.chunk_id,
        ),
        reference=config["genome"]["custom_genome_path"],
        idx=idx,
    params:
        bwa=config["map"]["mapper"],
        extra="-SP",
        sort="none",
        dedup="none",
    log:
        "logs/bwa_memx/{library}.{run}.{chunk_id}.log",
    threads: 8
    output:
        pipe(f"outputs/mapped_chunks/{{library}}.{{run}}.{{chunk_id}}.bam"),
    wrapper:
        "v1.24.0/bio/bwa-memx/mem"

rule parse_sort_chunks:
    input:
        bams="outputs/mapped_chunks/{library}.{run}.{chunk_id}.bam",
        chromsizes=config["genome"]["chrom_sizes_path"],
    threads: 8
    params:
        dropsam_flag="--drop-sam" if config["parse"].get("drop_sam", False) else "",
        dropreadid_flag="--drop-readid"
        if config["parse"].get("drop_readid", False)
        else "",
        dropseq_flag="--drop-seq" if config["parse"].get("drop_seq", True) else "",
        parsing_options=config["parse"].get("parsing_options", ""),
        keep_bams_command=f"| tee >(samtools view -bS > outputs/mapped_chunks/{{library}}.{{run}}.{{chunk_id}}.{custom_genome_name}.bam)"
        if config["parse"]["keep_unparsed_bams"]
        else "",
    output:
        f"outputs/parsed_chunks/{{library}}.{{run}}.{{chunk_id,[0-9]+}}.{custom_genome_name}.pairs.gz",
    shell:
        """
        cat {input.bams} {params.keep_bams_command} |
        pairtools parse {params.dropsam_flag} {params.dropreadid_flag} {params.dropseq_flag} \
        {params.parsing_options} \
        -c {input.chromsizes} \
        | pairtools sort --nproc {threads} \
        -o {output} \
        """
```

Finally, I need to merge the output of the previous rule, generating one file for each *library* - combining all *runs* together. I know the list of all runs for each library, I knows that for each run there is always two values of *side* (1 or 2). I don't know how many and what *chunk_id* I have.

With the implementation below the problem is that my merging function only has one wildcard - *library*, and missing the *run* and *side* checkpoints. Hence, I can not check the output of the checkpoint - it needs to have all the wildcards!

```
def get_pair_chunks(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.chunk_fastq.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand(
        "outputs/parsed_chunks/{library}.{run}.{chunk_id}.{custom_genome_name}.pairs.gz",
        library=wildcards.library,
        run=wildcards.run,

        chunk_id=glob_wildcards(
            f"outputs/fastq_chunks/{wildcards.library}.{wildcards.run}.{wildcards.side}/{{chunk_id}}.fastq.gz",
        ).chunk_id,
        custom_genome_name=custom_genome_name,
    )

rule merge_sort_dedup:
    input:
        pairs=get_pair_chunks,
    params:
        dedup_options=lambda wildcards: config["dedup"].get("dedup_options", ""),
    threads: 8
    output:
        multiext(
            f"outputs/library_pairs/{{library}}.{custom_genome_name}",
            ".nodups.pairs.gz",
            ".nodups.bam",
            ".unmapped.pairs.gz",
            ".unmapped.bam",
            ".dups.pairs.gz",
            ".dups.bam",
            ".dedup.stats",
        ),
     shell:
         f"""pairtools merge {{input.pairs}}) --nproc {{threads}}""" # and more stuff here
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to merge in two steps. First merge all your chunks back into a file that still contains the `run` and `side` wildcards. And in a second step merge all the `run`s (and `side`s?) per `library`.

Generally speaking, you have to options:

1. Your aggregation step input function has exactly the same wildcards as your checkpoint-scattering rule. For this, the docs give a good example: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution
2. Your aggregation step input function determines the value of certain parts of the input file name that are wildcards in the checkpoint rule from other logic, for example by parsing some `samples.tsv` file or by looking stuff up in the `config` dictionary.

Also, a further sidenote: if you can make the number of chunks produced at the scattering step fixed (and often you can), then the [snakemake `scatter-gather` process](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#defining-scatter-gather-processes) is a much more efficient way to encode this. `checkpoint`s are always a bit hacky and create quite a bit of overhead in the handling of the directed acyclic graph (DAG) of rule dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a possible solution, although it will be slower, and I don't understand how to deal with `side` then. Since it's used in the splitting rule, but after the intermediate processing the `side` disappears (two sides are combined...)

Comment: Either you also get the `side` merging outside of your scatter-gather, or you use the same function that you do for determining the values of `side` within your scattered rules, to also determine the values of `side` in the gathering rule input function.

Comment: I ended up doing this hierarchical merging, and simply hardcoded some stuff to deal with `side` and not have it as a wildcard. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers for the follow-up. I also extended the answer a bit, to make it more useful for others coming here, as well.

Comment: since you already looked at my code, I would appreciate help on another issue that I don't understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75821726/checkpoint-rule-with-directory-as-output-inferring-wrong-wildcards