# Checkpoint rule with directory as output inferring wrong wildcards

Tags: snakemake

Here is an excerpt from my Snakefile.

Checkpoint rule:

```
checkpoint chunk_fastq:
    input:
        fastq1=lambda wildcards: (
            f"downloaded_fastqs/{wildcards.library}.{wildcards.run}.1.fastq.gz"
            if needs_downloading(
                LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wildcards.library][wildcards.run], 0
            )
            else LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wildcards.library][wildcards.run][0]
        ),
        fastq2=lambda wildcards: (
            f"downloaded_fastqs/{wildcards.library}.{wildcards.run}.2.fastq.gz"
            if needs_downloading(
                LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wildcards.library][wildcards.run], 1
            )
            else LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wildcards.library][wildcards.run][1]
        ),
    params:
        chunksize=lambda wildcards: config["map"]["chunksize"] * 4,
    threads: 4
    output:
        directory("outputs/fastq_chunks/{library}/{run}"),
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output};
        zcat {input.fastq1} | split -l {params.chunksize} -d \
            --filter 'bgzip -c -@ {threads} > $FILE.fastq.gz' - \
            {output}/1.
        zcat {input.fastq2} | split -l {params.chunksize} -d \
            --filter 'bgzip -c -@ {threads} > $FILE.fastq.gz' - \
            {output}/2.
        """
```

Intermediate rules that operate on the output of the checkpoint:

```
rule map_chunks_bwa:
    input:
        reads=[
            "outputs/fastq_chunks/{library}/{run}/1.{chunk_id}.fastq.gz",
            "outputs/fastq_chunks/{library}/{run}/2.{chunk_id}.fastq.gz",
        ],
        reference=config["genome"]["custom_genome_path"],
        idx=idx,
    params:
        bwa=config["map"]["mapper"],
        extra="-SP",
        sort="none",
        dedup="none",
    log:
        "logs/bwa_memx/{library}/{run}/{chunk_id}.log",
    threads: 8
    output:
        pipe("outputs/mapped_chunks/{library}/{run}/{chunk_id,[0-9]+}.bam"),
    wrapper:
        "v1.24.0/bio/bwa-memx/mem"


rule parse_sort_chunks:
    input:
        bams="outputs/mapped_chunks/{library}/{run}/{chunk_id}.bam",
        chromsizes=config["genome"]["chrom_sizes_path"],
    threads: 8
    params:
        dropsam_flag="--drop-sam" if config["parse"].get("drop_sam", False) else "",
        dropreadid_flag="--drop-readid"
        if config["parse"].get("drop_readid", False)
        else "",
        dropseq_flag="--drop-seq" if config["parse"].get("drop_seq", True) else "",
        parsing_options=config["parse"].get("parsing_options", ""),
        keep_bams_command=f"| tee >(samtools view -bS > outputs/mapped_chunks/{{library}}/{{run}}/{{chunk_id}}.{custom_genome_name}.bam)"
        if config["parse"]["keep_unparsed_bams"]
        else "",
    output:
        f"outputs/parsed_chunks/{{library}}/{{run}}/{{chunk_id,[0-9]+}}.{custom_genome_name}.pairs.gz",
    shell:
        """
        cat {input.bams} {params.keep_bams_command} |
        pairtools parse {params.dropsam_flag} {params.dropreadid_flag} {params.dropseq_flag} \
        {params.parsing_options} \
        -c {input.chromsizes} \
        | pairtools sort --nproc {threads} \
        -o {output} \
        """
```

Aggregating rule, and follow-up after that:

```
def get_pair_chunks(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.chunk_fastq.get(**wildcards).output
    chunk_ids = glob_wildcards(
        f"outputs/fastq_chunks/{wildcards.library}/{wildcards.run}/2.{{chunk_id}}.fastq.gz",
    ).chunk_id
    paths = expand(
        f"outputs/parsed_chunks/{wildcards.library}/{wildcards.run}/{{chunk_id}}.{custom_genome_name}.pairs.gz",
        chunk_id=chunk_ids,
    )
    return paths


rule merge_runs:
    input:
        get_pair_chunks,
    output:
        pipe(f"outputs/parsed_runs/{{library}}/{{run}}.{custom_genome_name}.pairs.gz"),
    shell:
        "echo {wildcards}; pairtools merge {input} --nproc {threads} -o {output}"


rule merge_dedup:
    input:
        pairs=lambda wildcards: expand(
            f"outputs/parsed_runs/{wildcards.library}/{{run}}.{custom_genome_name}.pairs.gz",
            run=list(LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wildcards.library].keys()),
        ),
    params:
        dedup_options=lambda wildcards: config["dedup"].get("dedup_options", ""),
    threads: 8
    output:
        multiext(
            f"outputs/library_pairs/{{library}}.{custom_genome_name}",
            ".nodups.pairs.gz",
            ".nodups.bam",
            ".unmapped.pairs.gz",
            ".unmapped.bam",
            ".dups.pairs.gz",
            ".dups.bam",
            ".dedup.stats",
        ),
    shell:
        f"""pairtools merge {{input.pairs}}) --nproc {{threads}}""" #Some more stuff here
```

When I try to run the pipeline requesting the output of the last rule above, I get an error due to incorrect wildcard inference...

```
InputFunctionException in line 114 of /tungstenfs/scratch/ggiorget/ilya/seq_data/microC/C-integration-mapping/workflow/Snakefile:
Error:
  KeyError: '1C8+20N+Bxb1_clone_1C1/lane1'
Wildcards:
  library=1C8+20N+Bxb1_clone_1C1/lane1
  run=1.01.fastq.gz
Traceback:
  File "/tungstenfs/scratch/ggiorget/ilya/seq_data/microC/C-integration-mapping/workflow/Snakefile", line 119, in <lambda>
```

Line 119 corresponds to `LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS[wildcards.library][wildcards.run], 0` in the lambda function for fastq1 in rule `chunk_fastq`.

From the `--debug-dag` output I can see that the wildcards are correct in all rules it tries to run, and the error happens immediately after

```
candidate job map_chunks_bwa
    wildcards: library=1C8+20N+Bxb1_clone_1C1, run=lane1, chunk_id=01
```

So up until the last moment everything is correct and as expected. At the same time, the output of `chunk_fastq` is actually already there, so it is even more confusing.

Comment: Do you need to add in a wildcard constraint?  It seems odd to have a path separator in your wildcard for library.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of constraint would help, since library and run can have any value... But I do have all of them in the config.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, using `wildcard_constraints` helps. The issue probably came from special characters in the `library` wildcard values... Since writing the wildcard constraints was annoying because of them, I had to add this, to escape all special characters, otherwise it just wouldn't work:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    library=f"({'|'.join([re.escape(lib) for lib in LIBRARY_RUN_FASTQS.keys()])})",
    run=f"({'|'.join([re.escape(run) for run in runs])})",
```

Had to spend a good couple of hours debugging this, since after adding wildcard constraints in the naive way just wouldn't let snakemake recognize anything.